# Is Ontology File created in Protege with RDF/XML Format a RDF file or the OWL file?

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, protege

I have created the ontology file in the Protege and save it in the RDF/XML format.
It also contains the OWL tag.

So, the ontology file created by Protege and saved as RDF/XML format are actually the RDF files or the RDF form of the OWL files or the OWL format containing the RDF also or something else ?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE rdf:RDF [
    <!ENTITY owl "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#" >
    <!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
]>

<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/q49f318b/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-13#"
     xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/q49f318b/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-13"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
    <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/q49f318b/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-13"/> 
    <!-- 
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //
    // Classes
    //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     -->
    <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/q49f318b/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-13#Student -->
    **<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/q49f318b/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-13#Student"/>**  
  <!-- http://www.semanticweb.org/q49f318b/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-13#University -->

    **<owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/q49f318b/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-13#University"/>
</rdf:RDF>**
<!-- Generated by the OWL API (version 3.4.2) http://owlapi.sourceforge.net -->
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's the RDF/XML serialization of the RDF mapping of your OWL ontology.

An OWL ontology is a set of axioms.  It can be serialized directly in a number ways:  the Manchester syntax, the OWL/XML standard, and Functional Syntax are all options.  An OWL ontology can also be mapped to a set of RDF triples, as described in [OWL 2 Web Ontology Language 
Mapping to RDF Graphs (Second Edition)](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-mapping-to-rdf-20121211/).  Now, RDF can be serialized in a bunch of different formats, too,  e.g., RDF/XML, Turtle, N3, and N-Triples.

So, you've got the RDF/XML serialization of the RDF mapping of an OWL ontology.  So it **is** an RDF file, because it's the serialization of an RDF graph.  It **also** makes sense to call it an OWL file, because it's an OWL ontology.  In fact, many of  the OWL files you'll find online are RDF/XML serializations of RDF mappings of OWL ontologies.

### Examples

Your OWL ontology can be written in a number of ways.  For instance, in the [functional syntax](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-syntax-20121211/):

```
Prefix(xsd:=<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>)
Prefix(owl:=<http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>)
Prefix(:=<http://www.semanticweb.org/q49f318b/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-13#>)
Prefix(xml:=<http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace>)
Prefix(rdf:=<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>)
Prefix(rdfs:=<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>)

Ontology(<http://www.semanticweb.org/q49f318b/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-13>

Declaration(Class(:Student))
Declaration(Class(:University))
)
```

In the OWL/XML serialization:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Ontology [
    <!ENTITY xsd "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" >
    <!ENTITY xml "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" >
    <!ENTITY rdfs "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" >
    <!ENTITY rdf "http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" >
]>
<Ontology xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
     xml:base="http://www.semanticweb.org/q49f318b/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-13"
     xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
     xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
     xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
     ontologyIRI="http://www.semanticweb.org/q49f318b/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-13">
    <Prefix name="xsd" IRI="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"/>
    <Prefix name="owl" IRI="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"/>
    <Prefix name="" IRI="http://www.semanticweb.org/q49f318b/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-13#"/>
    <Prefix name="rdf" IRI="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"/>
    <Prefix name="rdfs" IRI="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"/>
    <Declaration>
        <Class IRI="#Student"/>
    </Declaration>
    <Declaration>
        <Class IRI="#University"/>
    </Declaration>
</Ontology>
<!-- Generated by the OWL API (version 3.2.5.1912) http://owlapi.sourceforge.net -->
```

These are different *serializations* of the *same* OWL ontology.  Because they're serializations of an OWL ontology, it makes sense to call them OWL files.

One more way to serialize an OWL ontology is an RDF Graph.  An RDF graph is an abstract thing though;  it's just a set of triples.  [OWL 2 Web Ontology Language Mapping to RDF Graphs (Second Edition)](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/REC-owl2-mapping-to-rdf-20121211/) describes the RDF mapping of OWL ontologies.  So from the OWL ontology, you can generate a set of RDF triples, i.e., an RDF graph.  An RDF graph can be written in a number of different formats, too, though.  Here's the RDF Graph for your OWL ontology in a few different RDF serializations.  All of the following are the *same* RDF graph.  SInce all of these are RDF serializations, it makes sense to call of them RDF files.  Since they're RDF encodings of an OWL ontology, it also makes sense to call them OWL files.

In the Turtle RDF serialization:

```
@prefix :      <http://www.semanticweb.org/q49f318b/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-13#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

<http://www.semanticweb.org/q49f318b/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-13>
        a       owl:Ontology .

:University  a  owl:Class .

:Student  a     owl:Class .
```

In the N-Triples serialization (one triple per line):

```
<http://www.semanticweb.org/q49f318b/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-13> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Ontology> .
<http://www.semanticweb.org/q49f318b/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-13#University> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class> .
<http://www.semanticweb.org/q49f318b/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-13#Student> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class> .
```

In RDF/XML with no "shortcuts":

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/q49f318b/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-13#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#" > 
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/q49f318b/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-13">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Ontology"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/q49f318b/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-13#University">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class"/>
  </rdf:Description>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/q49f318b/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-13#Student">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Class"/>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

In RDF/XML using some of the shortcuts:

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns="http://www.semanticweb.org/q49f318b/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-13#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
  <owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/q49f318b/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-13"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/q49f318b/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-13#University"/>
  <owl:Class rdf:about="http://www.semanticweb.org/q49f318b/ontologies/2014/5/untitled-ontology-13#Student"/>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: RDF and OWL are two representation formats for the web semantics information. What do you mean by RDF mapping of an OWL ontology ? Is it the conversion from OWL to RDF ? You have used the RDF graph and OWL ontology for the same document. what does it means ?

Comment: An OWL ontology is a kind of thing.  You can represent it in a bunch of ways. One of those ways is a set of RDF triples.  But then there are a bunch of ways to write  RDF triples, too.  So you've taken an OWL ontology, and represented it as a set of RDF triples.  Then you took the set of RDF triples and wrote it using the RDF/XML serialization.

Comment: Thanks, What is the meaning of using the shortcuts in the RDF/XML ?
If I want the RDF/XML format to store in some database. Is it fine to have RDF/XML with shortcuts ?
Do we need to convert the RDF/XML with shortcuts to the RDF/XML without shortcuts ? Is Protege supports it ?

Comment: Yes, all the tools should support it.  RDF/XML is a very complicated syntax, and (in my opinion) it's only common because it was the only format that tools were required to support, and because there were already lots of XML processing tools when RDF was invented.  But see how the *same* RDF graph can be written in RDF/XML in one way that uses `rdf:Description` elements and another that uses `owl:Ontology` and `owl:Class` elements?  It confused people, even though it's the *same* graph.  You should think about RDF as a *set* of triples, and not worry about the particular serialization formats.